# Find equation of the tangent line to $y=x^2$ at the point $x=3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find equation of the tangent line to  $y=x^2$ at  the point $x=3$

I tried to use derivatives and I found out the derivative is $2x$. How to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it!  The derivative is $2x$.  So at $x=3$, the slope is $2*3=6$.

Now you have the slope, all you need is a point.  Your function is $f(x)=x^2$.  So at $x=3$, a point is $(3,3^2)$ or $(3,9)$.

Now you have a point and the slope.  Use the point slope formula to write the equation of your line.

Comment: but what is the equation

Comment: i get it so u use y-y1=m(x-x1)

Comment: @hydua exactly.  :)

Comment: do u mind if i ask you another question what if the function was the square root of x at x=9....

Comment: @hydua not at all.  How do you think you would proceed?  Try drawing the function and the tangent line for the first part where x=3.  And then try to do the same thing for x=9.  What points on the plot did you use?  How did you get the slope of the line?

Comment: never mind I found it its, (1/6)x+(3/2)

Comment: @lovey that's not right.  What is the slope of the function at x=9?  And what is a point on the function at x=9?